# Heroku rails-problems ((syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' in textarea-form-helper)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm trying to push my rails application on the heroku cedar-stack.
Everything works fine on my local machine (Ruby Version 1.9.3 and rails version 3.2.6)

When i push my app to heroku, i get the following error in my _post_form-partial (see code below):

```
/app/app/views/posts/_post_form.html.erb:9: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
2012-07-18T11:25:36+00:00 app[web.1]: ...:id =>"textarea", :cols => "5", :rows => "8", :class => "inp...
2012-07-18T11:25:36+00:00 app[web.1]: ...                               ^
2012-07-18T11:25:36+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/views/posts/_post_form.html.erb:9: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
2012-07-18T11:25:36+00:00 app[web.1]: ...a", :cols => "5", :rows => "8", :class => "inputx-large boxs...
2012-07-18T11:25:36+00:00 app[web.1]: ...                               ^
2012-07-18T11:25:36+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/views/posts/_post_form.html.erb:9: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
2012-07-18T11:25:36+00:00 app[web.1]: ... => "inputx-large boxsizing") );@output_buffer.safe_concat('
2012-07-18T11:25:36+00:00 app[web.1]: ...                               ^):
```

I really don't get the problem here. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div id="inputfield_visible_wrapper">
    <div class="well">
        <input type="text" id="inputfield_visible" class="input-xlarge boxsizing" value="Create Posting here">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="form_hidden_wrapper">
    <%= form_for Post.new, :html => { :class => "well" } do |f| %>
        <%= render "shared/posting_information" %>
        <%= f.text_area (:content, :id =>"textarea", :cols => "5", :rows => "8", :class => "inputx-large boxsizing") %>
        <%= f.submit "Post", :disabled => true, :id => "submit_button", :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
        <%= submit_tag "Cancel", :class => "btn", :id => "cancel_button", :type => "button" %>
        <div class="characters_left_wrapper">
            <span id="characters_left">100</span> <span class="hidden-phone">Characters left</span>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: You should remove the space after `f.text_area`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't put trailing spaces on methods before the parentheses:

```
<%= f.text_area (:content) %>
```

bad

```
<%= f.text_area(:content) %>
```

good